# How to find a anchor tag with a particular text that is in a nav bar?

Tags: jquery

when a page loads i need to find an anchor tag with `"home"` text and set a class to it(`<a>`). Assume this anchor tag is in a `<ul><li><a>Home</a></li></ul>` (navbar)... How do do it?

Once the class is set it should look like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector like this:

```
$('a:contains("Home")') //contains "Home" ?
 .parent()//select its parent 'li'
 .addClass('active');//add class 'active' to 'li'
```

Comment: it has to set the class like this <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

Comment: TX its solved : ) but i have to wait 8 mins to mark as answer